# Zend Framework: select distinct rows by two fields

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have in a dbtable

```
field 1   field 2
1         2
2         3
2         3
2         2
1         1
2         2
```

I want to get

```
field 1 field 2
1       2
2       3
2       2
1       1
```

Tried

```
$select = $this->_dbTable->select()->from($this->_dbTable,array("DISTINCT(field_1) as field_1","DISTINCT(field_2) as field_2"));
$select = $this->_dbTable->select()->from($this->_dbTable,array("DISTINCT(field_1, field_2) as field_1, field_2"));
```

PS: Why this Zend Framework's so hard?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sashi Kant suggested this can be done by a group by on field_1, field_2. Here is how to make it using Zend DB :

```
$select = $this->_dbTable->select()->from($this->_dbTable, array("field_1", "field_2"))
                                   ->group(array("field_1", "field_2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Select 
field1,
field2
from mytable
group by field1, field2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zend_Db_Expr too

Try this:

```
$select = $this->_dbTable->select()->from($this->_dbTable, new Zend_Db_Expr('DISTINCT(field_1) as field_1'));
```